# session_regenerate_id вопрос

Tags: php

Сделал простую авторизацию у себя на сайте, сессионную, без применения "запомнить меня".

Вот вопрос возник такой.

Я в сессии при авторизации записываю

```
    $hash = md5(uniqid());
    $fullHash = md5(md5($hash.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $qSelPswd->id;
    $_SESSION['u_hash'] = $hash;
```

В базу я записываю **$fullHash**

При проверке авторизации я проверяю на равенство **$fullHash**,
то есть беру при проверке ИП юзера $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] и Хэш из сессии, и генерирую **$fullHash**, после чего проверяю на соответствие в базе.

Казалось бы мне что все хорошо и надежно, но, если хакер сворует куку PHPSESSID и подставит себе , как и пошлет заголовок с ИП жертвы и получит доступ... Беда.

Почитал , наткнулся на **session_regenerate_id(true);**

При каждом обновлении сайта генерируется новый ид текущей сессии и обновляет его не только в куках но и на сервере, вроде бы хорошо работает, но при частом обновлении - "ломает сессию". Не в этом беда, вообще хотел узнать стоит ли использовать эту вещь? Или как то иначе обойти сессионую авторазацию?

Comment: Айпишник имеет право смениться во время сессии. Представьте, что кто-то путешествует с ноутбуком.

Comment: да, все верно... Тогда проверять по браузеру - HTTP_USER_AGENT, но его ведь можно заголовком послать, и все равно будет доступ...
Как быть?
Много материала прочитал за последние несколько часов, но единого решения так и не нашел

Comment: версия браузера тоже может измениться https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#User_Agent

Comment: кука сессионая, изменится версия браузера - лучше перезайдет юзер и посмотрит логи входа, а так хоть минимальная проверка.
Смотрю сейчас эта херь работает на разных сайтах и форумах, проверил IPB 3.x+ подставив куки с одного браузера в другой - все заработало. Так что как я понял это серьёзный вопрос

Comment: User-Agent меняется тупо от поворота экрана устройства. Я позже постараюсь написать полноценный ответ, но ни айпи, ни порт, ни user-agent не являются устойчивым идентификатором пользователя.